# Looking up a person in sharepoint workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have one list called Teams. The Teams item has two columns Leader and Members.    Both are people fields with the Members being multiple values.

I have a second list called Requests.  In a Requests Sharepoint designer workflow, I want to lookup the creator of the item against the Members column of the Teams list and set the Leader field on  Requests to the value returned in the Leader column in Teams list.

I can't even get the lookup to work let alone setting the Leader people column in requests.

Can anyone tell me how I can lookup a person in another list against a people column with multiple values?   Is it even possible?

We are using SharePoint 2013 but only 2010 workflows are enabled.

Comment: So What I have understand is: Requests list contains a column "Leader". When a Request Item is created, you want to match the creator of request with member of Teams list, pull leader from Teams list and set it in Requests list.. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes that is pretty much what I wrote.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2013 with SPD2013 workflows of platform type 2013?

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that.   We are using SharePoint 2013 but only 2010 workflows are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work.   I used Login Name as the type for the key and the field it is looking up against.  Tried that before, no idea why it wa not working before but it is now.